# Limit the length of elements in trucate property of vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the truncate property of vuejs to add the feature of read more and read less. I am stuck at this point and I am not able to figure out how to add the length to be equal to the first two items in the array. I am trying something like this but it just shows the first two characters of the first item in the array instead of the first two items in the array.

```
<truncate
 action-class="action"
 clamp="..."
 class="quotation"
 :length="worker.jobs.length=2"
 less="read less"
 :text="worker.jobs"
 type="html"
 >
</truncate>

<script>
 import truncate from 'vue-truncate-collapsed';
 export default {
  components: {
    truncate
  },
  data: () => ({
    workers: [],
    truncate: truncate
  })
 };

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share where / how is the truncate component defined?

Comment: @Psidom I have edited the question and added the script tag info. Please have a look.

Comment: What do you mean the first two items? what if the first two items have different length?

Comment: what is `worker`? can't see where that's declared. What is `worker.jobs` - looks like it may be a String not an Array

Comment: @Psidom by the first two items what I am trying to mean is that suppose there is an array [jamie, jack, wilson] so I want to limit the length to just [jamie, jack] and when I click on read more I can see all the items that is [jamie, jack, wilson]

Comment: So you are trying to truncate the list not the text? That doesn't seem to be what this package is for. It explicitly says that it's used for [truncate your text and adds a "Read Me/Show Less" clickable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-truncate-collapsed).

Comment: @Psidom Please can you suggest what should I use?

Comment: Don't know if there's a component for that. But maybe [this vue pagination component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-paginate) can give you some idea.